# Rieman-Stieltjes Integral problems

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

I wanted to solve the following Riemann- Stieltjes problems:

Calculate

(a) $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x d(\sin x)$

(b) $\int_{-1}^{3}x~dg(x)$ where $g(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{for $x=-1,$}\\
1,  & \text{for $-1<x<2,$}\\
-1,  & \text{for $-1\leq x\leq 2.$}
\end{cases}$

(c)  $\int_{-2}^{2}x~dg(x)$ where $g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+2,  & \text{for $-2\leq x\leq -1,$}\\
2,  & \text{for $-1<x<0,$}\\
x^2+3,  & \text{for $0\leq x\leq 2.$}
\end{cases}$

I try to solve (a) as follows: Since $\sin x$ is differentiable on $0<x<\pi/2,$ so that (a) changes to Riemann integral by using the following theorem:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)=\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx.$$
So, I obtained 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x~d(\sin x)= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} x\cos x dx=1.$$
Please, Is the solution (a) correct?

Part (b), I try to solve it the following way; 
$$\int_{-1}^{3} x dg(x)= \int_{-1}^{-1} x g'(x)dx+\int_{-1}^{2} x g'(x)dx+\int_{2}^{3} x g'(x)dx.$$
But, I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

I don't know how to solve part (c) at all. I need a help on how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\;(\sin x)=\cos x\;$ , **not** $\;-\cos x\;$ .

Comment: For (b) you have redefined the same function over part of the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parts:

$$(a)\;\;\begin{cases}u=x,&u'=1\\v'=\cos x,&v=\sin x\end{cases}\implies\left.\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos xdx=x\sin x\right|_0^{\pi/2}-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin xdx=$$

$$=\left.\frac\pi2+\cos x\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac\pi2-1$$

Your idea for (b) is good: you shall get zero at the end. For (c) you can do the same as for (b):

$$\int_{-2}^2xdg(x)=\int_{-2}^{-1}x\cdot1\,dx+\int_{-1}^0x\cdot0\,dx+\int_0^2x\cdot2x\,dx=$$

$$\left.\frac12x^2\right|_{-2}^{-1}+0+\left.\frac23x^3\right|_0^2=\frac12(1-4)+\frac23(8-0)=-\frac32+\frac{16}3=\frac{23}6$$

Comment: You need to add the contributions from the jump discontinuities.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $g$ for the case b is in fact
$$g(x) = \cases{0 & $x = -1$ \\ 1 & $-1 < x < 2$ \\ -1 & $2 \le x \le 3$}.$$
Let $f(x) = x$. The integral is just the sum of the contributions from the jump discontinuities of $g$:
$$I = \int_{-1}^3 f(x) dg(x) = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}
\{ f(-1) (g(-1 + \epsilon) - g(-1)) +
 f(2) (g(2 + \epsilon) - g(2 - \epsilon)) \} = -5.$$
Alternatively, $I$ can be calculated as
$$I = f(3) g(3) - f(-1) g(-1) - \int_{-1}^3 g(x) df(x) = -5.$$
The case c is similar.